# how to use jquery to load from array of pages - in order

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, load, append

I'm grabbing a bunch of links from a page and then pulling in a specific content element from those pages. The code I just created works and does just that.

The problem is because the requests are asynchronous, the elements are not loading up in order. I tried adding a delay but that didn't work.

Do I need to be using .ajax instead of .load? If so, what would this looped append look like with .ajax command? Can you still use a selector with the url? Or is there an effective way to acheive this with .load?

Thanks in advance.

```
    function runthis() {

var links = $("#article-slide-belt a").map(function() {
                return this.href;
            }).get();

$.each( links, function(i, l){

    $("<div>").load(l + " .gl_left", function() {
          $(".gl_left").append($(this).find(".gl_left").html());
    });

 });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue

Comment: this looks cool but also unsure how to use... i'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: i couldn't get ajax queue to work properly but i did search around and found http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/ which is similar conceptually and does work. I up-voted Michal's answer for good advice and the education but a queue was the right answer. bookmarklet script performing great now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the next link to load on completion of the first request - the code below is not very elegant but it will do what you want

```
var links
var content_index=0;
$(document).ready( function() {
    links = $("#article-slide-belt a").map( function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get();
    loadContent()
})
function loadContent() {
    if (content_index<links.length) {
        $("div").load(links[content_index] + " .gl_left", function() {
            $(".gl_left").append($(this).find(".gl_left").html());
            content_index++;
            loadContent();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's hanging / browser-crashing when I try and execute it. http://ohword.com/simplex.js <-- it's meant to be a bookmarklet. it combines the content from every panel of a slideshow on a particular site and displays them all in one page instead of having to click through each. do you see an error in the code as i've pasted it?

Comment: oh wait... i think i found the problem there... missing semicolon after var links

Comment: for a bookmarklet you probably do not need document ready block and also have my functions contained in your runthis() function, considering I am calling loadContent recursively this might result in a browser crash. I do not have much experience in bookmarklets so I am not sure what else might be going wrong.

Comment: you also need to make sure that both links and content_index variable are global in scope

Comment: sorry can you help me figure out where i'm going wrong. http://ohword.com/simplex.js i changed the scope to global and got rid of the document ready block

Comment: ... but now i notice loadcontent keeps running even after content_index passes the links.length. i can see this behavior from the alerts.

Comment: got the bookmarklet working now using http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/ <- nifty script for queueing ajax requests. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the synchronous .ajax route. And it comes in correct order but the wait is unbearable. Needs to be readable page while the data is loading in.

```
$.each( links, function(i, l){

$.ajax({        
     url: l,                         
     async: false,         
     success: function(data){
    var $response=$(data);

    $(".gl_left").append($response.find(".gl_left").html());

    }     
     });

 });
```

Comment: I think that recursion is probably a better way to go about it. You should launch the next load on the success of the first one.